# Windows blocks program to summon browser

Tags: windows, windows-7, browser

Recently I have been facing some issues with some of my installed programs. Custom programs to access and program microcontrollers.
Some of these programs have kind of internet guides, which you would be then redirected to the internet guide in your browser.

After recent updates, this redirection to local browser isn’t working anymore. When I click on the intended button, nothing happens (no error whatsoever).

I thought the problem was with the update, but another program (different vendor) also stopped working. It seems like after new updates, this functionality is blocked.

Can I access something like a log  of my Windows OS to see what is happening in the „backend“? Or any ideas what is happening?

Comment: Do you have a browser set in Default Apps? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/change-which-programs-windows-7-uses-by-default-62fd162f-8c82-0436-806f-c60d69dcf495

Comment: @Gantendo as far as I know, that would be Firefox. At least that’s what it says in the Default App. May the Program be trying to access e.g., Edge?

Comment: @infinitedreamer666 - Do you even have Edge installed on your Windows 7 system? Edge support on Windows 7 ended in January 2023. If it's installed it would have no problem running it. Exact error messages or screenshots of dialogs are always appreciated.

Comment: `backend` ? SURE! :)  You can familiarize yourself with the [Process monitor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) which will indeed provide you with this information.  You should know that this tool takes a bit of getting used to.  It dishes out a tremendous amount of information and you will need to use the filters to get it down to chunks a human brain can consume.  A master of this tool can figure out just about anything.

Comment: Solved. I was using a portable browser and the system was not recognizing any browser as default.